# R - readRDS() & load() fail to give identical data.tables as the original

Tags: r, save, load, data.table

**Background**

I tried to replace some `CSV` output files with `rds` files to improve efficiency. These are intermediate files that will serve as inputs to other R scripts.

**Question**

I started investigating when my scripts failed and found that `readRDS()` and `load()` do not return identical `data tables` as the original. Is this supposed to happen? Or did I miss something?

**Sample code**

```
library( data.table )

aDT <- data.table( a=1:10, b=LETTERS[1:10] )
saveRDS( aDT, file = "aDT.rds")
bDT <- readRDS( file = "aDT.rds" )
identical( aDT, bDT, ignore.environment = T )  # Gives 'False'

aDF <- data.frame( a=1:10, b=LETTERS[1:10] )
saveRDS( aDF, file = "aDF.rds")
bDF <- readRDS( file = "aDF.rds" )
identical( aDF, bDF, ignore.environment = T )  # Gives 'True'

# Using 'save'& 'load' doesn't help either
aDT2 <- data.table( a=1:10, b=LETTERS[1:10] )
save( aDT2, file = "aDT2.RData")
bDT2 <- aDT2; rm( aDT2 )
load( file = "aDT2.RData" )
identical( aDT2, bDT2, ignore.environment = T )  # Gives 'False'
```

I am running R ver 3.2.0 on Linux Mint and have tested with `data.table` ver 1.9.4 and 1.9.5 (latest).

Searching in SO and google returned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345759/how-to-save-a-data-frame-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146684/readrds-loads-extra-packages) but I don't think they answer this issue. I am still trying to figure out why my scripts failed when I switched to `rds` but I am starting with this.

Would appreciate it very much if knowledgeable SO members can help. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Hi everyone, I happened to find a way to resolve the issue - have posted the solution below. I apologise if it's rather inelegant. Now, I have 2 further questions:

(1) Is there a better way?

(2) Can something be done at the `R` and/or `data.table` code to resolve this? I mean, this issue causes unpredictable bugs and is not the first thing that comes to mind. My 2 cents worth.

Comment: but then `all.equal(aDT, bDT)` #TRUE

Comment: Hmm... good point... I've always only use `identical`. Going through ?`all.equal` shows that it's a test for 'near-equality', so perhaps the difference is in the pointers as mentioned by the 2 gentlemen below?

Answer (score 4):

Probably, this has to do with pointers:

```
 attributes(aDT)
$names
[1] "a" "b"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$class
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

$.internal.selfref
<pointer: 0x0000000000390788>

> attributes(bDT)
$names
[1] "a" "b"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$class
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

$.internal.selfref
<pointer: (nil)>

> attributes(bDF)
$names
[1] "a" "b"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$class
[1] "data.frame"

> attributes(aDF)
$names
[1] "a" "b"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

You can closely look at what's going using `.Internal(inspect(.))` command:

```
.Internal(inspect(aDT))

 .Internal(inspect(bDT))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @user227710. Is there any way to re-establish the pointer for the `data table` that has been re-loaded, without access to the original DT?

Comment: @NoviceProg: Your issue is dicussed more in details [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/What-is-going-on-with-R-3-1-td4689002.html). `saveRDS` doesn't save the `.internal.selfref` so, I think it's not possible.

Comment: I went through the link you provided as well as the SO thread in the link. Interestingly, they mentioned the issue has been resolved in `data table` v1.9.3, not sure if that OP was facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

The newly loaded `data.table` doesn't know the pointer value of the already loaded one.  You could tell it with

```
attributes(bDT)$.internal.selfref <- attributes(aDT)$.internal.selfref
identical( aDT, bDT, ignore.environment = T )
# [1] TRUE
```

`data.frame` don't keep this attribute, probably because they don't do in place modification.

Comment: Hi @LegalizeIt, I see where you're heading but what happens if the script loading bDT does not have access to aDT? That's the reason for the intermediate files (`csv`/`rds`).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use `setDT` after `load` or `readRDS`

```
aDT2 <- readRDS("aDT2.RData")
setDT(aDT2)
```

source: [Adding new columns to a data.table by-reference within a function not always working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078640/adding-new-columns-to-a-data-table-by-reference-within-a-function-not-always-wor)

Answer (score 1):

I happen to find a way that resolves the issue (disclaimer: it's a rather inelegant way but it works!) - adding then deleting a dummy column in the loaded `data table` leads to `identical` being 'True'. I have also successfully replaced `csv` with `rds` intermediate files in my own code.

To be honest, I don't understand enough of the inner workings of R nor `data table` to know why it works, so any explanations and/or more elegant solutions would be welcomed.

```
library( data.table )

aDT <- data.table( a=1:10, b=LETTERS[1:10] )
saveRDS( aDT, file = "aDT.rds")
bDT <- readRDS( file = "aDT.rds" )
identical( aDT, bDT, ignore.environment = T )  # Gives 'False'

bDT[ , aaa := NA ]; bDT[ , aaa := NULL ]
identical( aDT, bDT, ignore.environment = T )  # Now gives 'True'


# Using the add-del-col 'trick' works here too
aDT2 <- data.table( a=1:10, b=LETTERS[1:10] )
save( aDT2, file = "aDT2.RData")
bDT2 <- aDT2; rm( aDT2 )
load( file = "aDT2.RData" )
identical( aDT2, bDT2, ignore.environment = T )  # Gives 'False'

aDT2[ , aaa := NA ]; aDT2[ , aaa := NULL ]
identical( aDT2, bDT2, ignore.environment = T )  # Now gives 'True'
```